# Prevent useEffect from triggering under certain conditions

Tags: reactjs

I got 2 Lists with the same content. The difference being: one is a normal List, the other is a detailed List with each List Entry having a nested List corresponding to them.
For Example:

```
Example 1:

normal List                     detailed List
House 1                         House 1
House 2                               Resident 1
                                      Resident 2
                                House 2
                                      Resident 3
```

Now i want to highlight the List Entry you click on in both Lists (and if you click on a nested List's entry it should highlight the corresponding parent entry in the normalList. eg: House 1 if you selected Resident 1 in the example above.)
Now i implemented it like this:

```
function detailedList(props){ 
    const context = useContext(ApplicationContext);
    const [selectedItem,setSelectedItem]=useState({id:null , level:"top",parent:null)

    const handleClick=(id,type,parent)=>{ 
//changes selected item if item in detailedList is clicked.
//if selected item is already a parent element then id equals parent
        setSelectedItem({id:id,type:type,parent:parent});
        context.setSelectedId(parent); //Problem Line

    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
//changes selected item if item in normalList is clicked.
            setSelectedItem({
                id: context.selectedId,
                level: "top",
                parent: context.selectedId,
            });
    }, [context.selectedId]); 

    return (
       ...
       //Renders the List
    )
}

//normalList just uses the context.selectedId to determine selected Item
```

So if, for example, you selected Resident 2 (see Example 1), selectedItem would be {id:2,level="nested",parent:1} and context.selectedId would be 1.
**The Problem now is: If you select a nested Item on the detailed List, which parent wasn't already selected, it selects the parent instead. That's because the *handleClick* function sets context.selectedId and therefore triggers the useEffect.**

So i would need a way to only trigger the useEffect if the change has its origin outside the component or something.

**Edit:**

I made a fiddle to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/hvf0s9t2/8/

Try selecting House 1 first and Person 5 second :/

Comment: Your problem is NOT with the useEffect, your problem is using the selectedId with 2 different values. It's like a magic global generic ID which can be anything from the phone-number to your IP address and it's up to the current context to decide which is which.

Comment: No, selectedId is ALWAYS the id of the parent Element. So in this example it can only contain the corresponding id to the houses, not the persons.  Edit: you are right. I made a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: I added a fiddle. That should probably help.

Comment: > Try selecting House 1 first and Person 5 second .. tried this on jsfiddle. It selects house-2 in both the lists. Is that not the expected behavior?

Comment: If i made the handleClick function async, then wrapped it in a function that did something like: ```writingInternaly=true; await HandleClick(); writingInternaly=false```... would the await last until the useEffect ran?

Comment: @jsN00b,   it should select House 2 in the first list and Person 5 in the second. And if you click a second time on Person 5 that happens. Only the first try is buggy :D